# Is a StatusBar created in simple mode by default?

Tags: c, winapi

When a StatusBar is first created, for example:

```
HWND hStatusBar = CreateWindowEx(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

Is it created in simple mode or in multiple-part mode? or maybe this is not guaranteed and it is better to set the mode I want after creating it?

Answer (score 0):

Status bars are created, as you have done, with a call to `CreateWindowEx`. When a status bar is first created it has no parts. Parts are added to status bars by sending a `SB_SETPARTS` message to the status bar.

> Is it created in simple mode or in multiple-part mode?

Simple mode without parts.

> Is it better to set the mode I want after creating it?

Parts can only by specified after the window has been created.